# radio Link works with laptop but not with PC

Tags: rf, wireless, radio, fsk

I have a complicated issue.

I set my HM-TRP radio modules to use:
117Khz receive bandwidth, 
39Khz deviation frequency and 
38Kbps air and data rate.

The attached picture is my basic room setup for the module operation. Details follow...

[image: test radio]

The "Test zone" is a wooden table and at the bottom right shown as a red circle is where one of my radio modules sit (attached to my circuit)

The box marked "Desktop" is my IBM think-center Desktop computer case.
Box next to it is a table and the flat panel monitor (shown as a vertical line) sits on top of it.
A little to the right of the monitor is the second radio module (see red circle) on the adjacent table.
To the left is the laptop.

**Back to the issue...**

With all my custom hardware setup being exactly the same, I ran tests as follows:

First test:

Desktop PC and monitor are turned off and unplugged. Laptop is running. 
I plug my hardware into the laptop, ran tests, and got no problems with any device.

Second test:

All computers powered on. I remove my hardware from laptop and plug it into Desktop PC. 
Communication to connected hardware via wire is fine, but the wireless connection seems to be non-existant ant when it should be.

For clarity, I used custom-made hardware between the PC and the wireless world and the custom hardware directly connects to the PC through the PC serial port. For all tests, the wired connections work.

I don't know if the power supply of the PC could be spreading noise over several centimeters? but is there anything else I can do to rectify this problem?

Comment: Use a USB cable with ferrites, see if that helps

Comment: These radios can put out up to 100mW (+20dB), which should overcome any noise. What power level are you using? - "the custom hardware directly connects to the PC through the PC serial port." - when you say 'serial' you mean USB, right? Show us your 'custom hardware'. - "the wireless connection **seems to be non-existant**" - what do the status LEDs show at each end when powered, transmitting, and receiving?

Comment: Earth grounding and tower CM noise is a common problem.  Show all your ground connections, shielding and earth ground connections

Comment: No serial is RS-232. And yes I set the transmit power on all radio modules to 100mW. By non-existant, I mean data isn't being exchanged over the radio all the time. Should I enclose my circuits (except the antennas) in a completely covered metal box and connect circuit board ground to it?